# Eclipse RCP custom launcher icon

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to replace the eclipse standard icon from my RCP application to a custom icon.

In my .product file I defined the 7 icons for windows and include it on my binary buil on buil.properties but when I export the application the icon still the default eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Have you included icons in Branding tab of .product file or just added them in Launching tab?